# Create only a single commit for multiple push commits in Git

Tags: git

I've a `fork` of the repo. I often create a new branch using

`git branch -t -b <myBranch> upstream/master`

For my local changes i do :

`git commit -m "my message"`

`git push origin myBranch`

Similarly to get the latest changes from `master`, I do :

`git fetch upstream`

`git merge upstream/master`

`git push origin myBranch`

All of the commits are the individual commits in the history, and it is often annoying. How can I keep in sync with `master` and yet only make a single commit of all my changes.

I've tried using `git rebase -i` but despite me squashing my own commits, it says merge conflicts a lot times and messes up the merge.

Comment: Have you tried `git pull --rebase`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with just one additional step... **to have all your changes in a single commit**. Right after merging upstream/master, do this:

```
git reset --soft upstream/master
git commit -m "All of my changes"
```

ok ok... so it was **two steps**. Now you can push.. but with -f because you are rewriting history

```
git push -f origin myBranch
```